# How to include current package version in NuGet transformation files?

Tags: nuget

I would like to include a content file into the package that should refer to the current version of the package being installed (more precisely to the package folder, but the only varying part is the version).

Is there a special syntax (e.g. $packageversion$ - does not work) to include the version number into a transformed (.pp) content file?

Alternative: I can access the version from the install.ps1 and I can also invoke Add-Content (i suppose that will also apply the transformations), but how can I extend the replacement placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables you can use (like $rootnamespace$) are the [ProjectProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.projectproperties_properties%28VS.80%29.aspx) so you won't be able to access the version number.

As a workaround, you could try naming the file as part of your build step that creates the NuGet package.

If you think it'd be good to see this added to NuGet, it's worth [starting a discussion](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions) on the NuGet site, the developers are pretty active there :-)